# postgreSQL group by or not

Tags: postgresql, group-by

I'm trying to group by the name the results.

The following code reproduces:

```
    name           |    time_     |   
-----------------------------------
    stackoverflow       3:00
    google              5:35
    stackoverflow       1:00

SELECT agenc.name, (SELECT CAST(servic.end_hour as time) - CAST(servic.begin_hour as time)) AS time_, jobs.name,
FROM services AS servic  
JOIN services_jobs AS jobs ON jobs.id = servic.job_id  
JOIN agency AS agenc ON agenc.id = jobs.agency_id
WHERE  
EXTRACT(MONTH FROM servic.service_date) = 9 AND  
EXTRACT(DAY FROM servic.service_date) = 16
```

And I want it to appears this way:

```
    name           |    time_     |   
-----------------------------------
    stackoverflow       4:00
    google              5:35
```

Is it possible? If so, how?

I thought about grouping, but I didn't get any result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difficult to help here, I guess you are looking for `sum` and `group by`:

```
select 
  agenc.name, 
  sum(cast(servic.end_hour as time) - cast(servic.begin_hour as time)) as time_
from 
  services as servic  
  join services_jobs AS jobs ON jobs.id = servic.job_id  
  join agency as agenc ON agenc.id = jobs.agency_id
where  
  extract(month from servic.service_date) = 9 and  
  extract(day from servic.service_date) = 16
group by
  agenc.name
```

Comment: Your code worked almost perfectly, I just needed to change the group by, for this: `GROUP BY 1,3,4`, because it retrieves error if I only group by name. Thanks!