# Python writing to excel

Tags: python, excel

I'd like to obtain the following structure:

```
                 Day 1   |    2    |   3    | 4       ... Total
stackoverflow                04:00            01:00       05:00
google             05:30               02:00              07:30
```

But with my code, I'm getting:

```
                 Day 1   |    2    |   3    | 4      ...  Total
stackoverflow                04:00                        04:00
google             05:30                                  05:30
stackoverflow                                01:00        01:00
google                               02:00                02:00
```

I have this query running (which was [given here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18846345/postgresql-group-by-or-not)):

```
select 
  agenc.name, 
  sum(cast(servic.end_hour as time) - cast(servic.begin_hour as time)) as time_, jobs.description
from 
  services as servic  
  join services_jobs AS jobs ON jobs.id = servic.job_id  
  join agency as agenc ON agenc.id = jobs.agency_id
where  
  extract(month from servic.service_date) = 9 and  
  extract(day from servic.service_date) = 16
group by
  agenc.name
```

And in the python, I do the same query, with the difference that the 'day column' from query "extract(day from servic.service_date)" is equal to the loop (from 1 to 31 -> day count)

```
query_A = cr.fetchall()
    if query_A:
        for values in query_A:
            sheet.write(line_, 0, values[0], style_main) # Writes the name
            sheet.write(line_, 1, values[2], style_main) # Writes the job

            current_value = str(values[1]);
            hours_ = current_value.split(':')[0]
            minutes_ = current_value.split(':')[1]
            total_ = hours_ +':'+ minutes_ # This will get 02:00 - for example

            sheet.write(line_, i + 1, total_, style_main) # write the result
            total_vertical += timedelta(hours=int(hours_), minutes=int(minutes_)) # here should sum the results along the days
            sheet.write(line_, 33, str(total_vertical), style_main) # write it on "total" column    
            line_ += 1

            total_vertical = timedelta(hours=0, minutes=0) # Reset
```

Any advice of how should I proceed to obtain the result I want? Thanks!

Comment: Can you shortly just explain what do you want to get and what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: @zenpoy it looks like the output is putting each result on its own line, rather than combining the matching rows into one single rows.

Comment: Yes, you're right @TankorSmash. But I think I've just found how to do it. I'll post here if this works, but any advice will be thankful

Comment: Yes, I just solved. Here's the full code: http://pastebin.com/kcH1bTMp
Thanks guys.

Comment: @user2742861 Can I suggest posting this as the answer to your own question please so that people do not continue to open this and review thinking that it is an unanswered question. You are able to mark your own answer as accepted two days after the question is posted, but think you can post the answer straight away (unless there are rep restrictions on this that I am not aware of).

Comment: Yes, of course. Done :D

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved, please see the code in the following link: http://pastebin.com/kcH1bTMp